# Iterating through an AngularJS resource with nested arrays

Tags: java, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have a small webapp that uses AngularJS on the front end and Java on the back-end. I am using REST for the communication.

On the back-end I am creating a list of lists, like this:

```
        List<List<Data>> allData = new ArrayList<>();
        allData.add(firstList);
        allData.add(secondList);
```

When this gets to the front-end, it looks like in the screenshot below - i.e. instead of being 2 Array[] objects within one Array[] object, it is 2 of these Resource objects with a list of Array[] objects. 
The problem is that I now want to iterate through this list of arrays and I don't know how to get the length of the list from this Resource object! I've tried length, size, count... all are undefined.

The question is how can I get it to keep the array within an array structure so I can easily iterate? Or how do I get the length from the Resource object?

TIA (Please excuse the newbie question).

[image]

Expanding aone of the Resource nodes:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you are experiencing is somehow related to the fact that in a `$resource` `query()` wherein the expected response data is an array, each data item in that array is converted into a Resource Object that contains instance action methods that is attached with a suffix `$`.

- **[Resource Object Conversion Reference](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.26/src/ngResource/resource.js#L552)**
- **[Resource Object Reference](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.26/src/ngResource/resource.js#L467)**

As you can see in the **Resource Object Reference** above, it performs a **[`shallowClearAndCopy()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.26/src/ngResource/resource.js#L30)** copy of the data item in the array that augments all of the properties of the data item to the Resource Object itself using the **[`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** which only iterates over **[enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)** properties. Since **[Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)**, is not an enumerable property then the augmentation of the `length` property in the **Resource** object from the array data item does not happen.

You have three ways to mend this problem:

[**1**] You can create a custom action method which has the same properties as the `query()` action method but with an additional **[transformResponse()](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource)** definition. The `transformResponse()` method is triggered after the request was made but before any promises are resolved. It is passed with a JSON string that you can convert to a regular json object via angular.fromJson() and iterate through all the arrays and augment each item object with a new enumerable property, lets call it `._length` and then return the new deserialized object for the promises to receive. This way, the `shallowClearAndCopy()` method copies the enumerable `_length` property and augments it to the Resource Object.

The code looks something like this:

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/sgei3Br8wHAssdodrdcF?p=preview)**

```
  var DataResource = $resource('data.json', null, {
    'getData': {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true,
      transformResponse: function(response) {
        var newData = JSON.parse(response);

        newData.map(function(data) {
          data._length = data.length;
          return data;
        });

        return newData;
      }
    }
  });

  DataResource.getData(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

You should notice that in the `console.log()`, it shows that each Resource Object item has a `_length` property that you can use.

[**2**] Another way is to use the `$http` service for this particular use case which is the simplest solution for this problem that I could think of.

```
$http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

[**3**] To reconsider the structure of your response data to something like this:

```
[{
  item: [1,2,3,4,5]
}, {
  item: [1,2,3,4,5]
}, {
  item: [1,2,3,4,5]
}, {
  item: [1,2,3,4,5]
}];
```

Then you can plainly use the `$resource` factory and iterate to each array item object with the `item` key.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed response, you are right on! I tried your code to add the length in and it worked. I'm going to either use that or look at restructuring my data, but both options mean iterating through the entire set, so I'll  need to see which is more performant. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the code handling resource reception ? I am guessing you use `$resource` service; 
If you want your data (e.g. for processing purposes), you need to take into account the asynchronous nature of the response : accesss the resource's `$promise` and provide a callback in order to retrieve the results. Code would probably look like :

```
myResouce.$promise.then(function(result) {
    $scope.data = result;
    console.log('length = ' + $scope.data.length);
}
```

If you actually don't need your data, `$resource` immediately returns an empty object that will be later populated by response contents. You could just do var `$scope.data = $resource(...);` and use this data object in your viewer. The view might start empty, but would then be updated whenever data are actually passed on to `$scope.data` from the `$resource` response.

Comment: yes I am using a $promise, and trying to iterate through the data once I have it all. It's the format the data is returned in that is the problem.